# HTML half table is scrollable while others is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm try to design a table which the left columns are fixed while right columns are scroll horizontally, and the header of the whole table is fixed during the scroll down. I have searched some solution but only able to fixed one column, my idea is in a table, can scroll like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 | column5 column6 column7 
------------------------------- |------------------------
                                |
//body and header are fixed     |  //only body and header can scroll  
//when scroll down              |  //horizontally, fixed while scroll 
                                |  //down
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to achieve your desired result

Comment: yes, I know, but I want to know any codes let me to refer to, as I have no idea how to start...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use two separate tables, in separate divs?  That way you can easily make one div scrollable however you want, and the other with different scrollable styling.  You can use `overflow-y: scroll` and `overflow-x: scroll` to make the parent div scrollable.

Comment: I already tried that, if use 2 tables, if size of data in table1 is different from table2, the rows will unmatched....

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
   table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

    tr:after {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }

    thead th {
        height: 30px;

        /*text-align: left;*/
    }

    tbody {
        height: 120px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    thead {
        /* fallback */
    }


    tbody td, thead th {
        width: 19.2%;
        float: left;
    }
```

And HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Based on this code I have created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/)

Comment: No, not even match a single requirement I want.

Comment: Try this link http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/ . i think this is best example for you.

Comment: Yes, that was my first example I refer to, I tried to modify the attribute, but still not working. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If u seperate the columns with divs, the design goal can be easily achieved. Apply the  specific CSS styles you want.

You can place the header of scrollable column in another div/span tag and make it fixed.

Comment: yes, it is, I have tried it, but not really a good design, because once the different data length will cause the rows in second table to be unmatched.

Comment: and actually I work it will database, for some reasons, separate table cannot be achieved.